# .net core 3.1 web api unable to remove escape character \n

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to achieve a simple goal here, just to remove \n from json string before parsing it to an object. but the same is not getting done even after trying various methods:

```
string xr = sw.ToString();
xr = xr.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);
xr = xr.Replace(@"\r\n","");
```

here, bothe of the methods are not working. FYI, sw is stringwriter which is fetching from MySql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
   xr = xr .Trim().Replace("\r", string.Empty);
   xr = xr .Trim().Replace("\n", string.Empty);
```